Independence of Random Variables Without The $\pi - \lambda$ Theorem
I am trying to show that the independence of random variables in measure theory is equivalent to the definition that we see in the non measure-theortic sense, specifically without the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.
I have been given the following definitions and lemmas:
$\textbf{Definition 1}$
Let $\{X_{α}\}_{α∈I}$ be a family of random variables, with $X_{α} : (Ω,\mathcal{F}) → (E_{α}, G_{α}).$ We say that
the random variables $X_{α}$ are independent if the family of sub $σ$-algebras $\{σ(X_{α})\}_{α∈I}$, is
independent.
$\textbf{Lemma 1}$
Let $X_{1},X_{2} : (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) → (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be two random variables. Show that $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are
independent according to the above definition, if and only if
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{1} ≤ a, X_{2} ≤ b) = \mathbb{P}(X_{1} ≤ a) \mathbb{P}(X_{2} ≤ b)
\quad \text{for every} \quad a ∈ \mathbb{R}, b ∈ \mathbb{R}.$$
Now, I know how to prove this using the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, which was my initial attempt and something I have seen repeated in books, but I was wondering whether there is a simpler proof that might not need to use it at all, or an alternative approach in and of itself.
So far, I thought of describing how a family of events would produce a $\sigma$-algebra and attempt to equate this to the $\sigma$-algebra produced by the random variables, but I believe that it does not account for the possible formulation of all possibilities of the pre-image of the random variables on an arbitrary borel-set of the real line.
Since, I've come up short, I wanted to know if there are other perspectives on proving this idea, or whether I might be able to alter my approach to make it work. What does everyone think?
